# rails3 jquery datepicker doesn't work on dynamically added form fields

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

when our event edit page is loaded, there are two date fields where the jquery datepicker is used and the picker also appears when I click on one of these fields.

datepicker is initialized when the document is loaded.

```
$ ->
  $(':input.date').datepicker(dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy')
```

and the class 'datepicker' is added automatically

```
<input class="span1 date hasDatepicker" id="event_application_opening_at" name="event[application_opening_at]" size="30" type="text">
```

because it's possible to add other dates to an event, we're creating additional, nested date fields when the user clicks on the "Add Date" link.

Although the "hasDatepicker" class is assigned to these fields correctly, the datepicker doesn't work on these newly created ones. It looks like this happens because the datepicker is initalized already. I tried to apply the destroy() function and then to re-initalize datepicker on the whole page content, but this didn't work.

Anyone out there who can help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $(":input.date").live("click", function(){
        $(this).datepicker({ 
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' 
        });
    });
```

update:

```
$(":input.date").live("click", function(){
            $(this).datepicker({ 
                dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' 
            });
          $(this).datepicker('show');

        });
```

Comment: this works, but I have to click into the field, leave it, and then click on it again until the datepicker appears

Comment: I now added select fields for hours and minutes just next to the date field where the Datepicker is active. when i click on one of these select boxes, the datepicker appears also on the date field which closes the select dropdown. Why's this happening?
the select item doesn't have the "date" class assigned

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to hynxnat's answer would be to bind to the "after:insert" event of whatever code you are using to add the fields. If you add your datepicker code to that event, it will ensure it binds to the fields that are on the page after the fields are inserted dynamically.

This would assume that you are using something like the Cocoon gem to added the extra fields.